# Indian Passport Holder travelling to India from UK during lockdown

Tags: uk, air-travel, indian-citizens, india, covid-19

I hold Indian Passport and  UK residence permit

I would like to travel india due to my fathers expected eye operation

Do I need to provide a doctors letter at UK airport before departure?

Comment: You would need to show why your journey was sufficiently necessary as to qualify as an exception, if you are asked. An eye operation doesn’t sound like a compelling reason unless there are other circumstances that could make it so. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162642/is-someone-elses-surgery-a-legally-permitted-reason-for-international-travel-fr

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to provide any reason to come back to India. As per the latest guidelines mentioned [here](https://boi.gov.in/sites/default/files/u4/Algorithmforinternationalarrivals.pdf), you would need to provide a negative RT-PCR report before boarding the flight. On arrival in India, your sample would be taken for checking new Covid-variants.

Comment: I believe there are some exit controls at UK to deter unnecessary travel _out_ and that seems to be OPs concern in this question. In India too they will need to quarantine for 7 days even if negative as they are coming from UK.

Comment: @RedBaron Could they stop the OP from travelling to their native country ? It's a home quarantine so no extra expenses are involved.

Comment: @Aak If the OP is resident in the UK, and is physically in the UK, they are subject to UK law. Which means stay at home, leaving only where permitted by law. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/national-lockdown-stay-at-home